# Prometheus JMX exporter and ActiveMQ

Tags: prometheus, activemq-classic, jmx-exporter

I am running AMQ with the [jmx_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter)   and using the provided config yaml file.

```
lowercaseOutputName: true
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: true
blacklistObjectNames:
  - "org.apache.activemq:clientId=*,*"
whitelistObjectNames:
  - "org.apache.activemq:destinationType=Topic,*"

rules:

  - pattern: org.apache.activemq<type=Broker, brokerName=(\S*), destinationType=Topic, destinationName=(\S*)><>(\w+)
    name: activemq_topic_$3
    attrNameSnakeCase: true
    labels:
      destination: $2
```

The output I get is something along with this:

```
activemq_topic_enqueue_count{destination="topic_1_name",} 0.0
```

My question:

Now, all attributes are being exposed to the endpoint while Im only interested in two, namely enqueue_count and dequeue_count. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Are you interested  only in those two or those two and other metrics exposed by jmx_exporter. If former, you can use relabeling with regex `activemq_topic_(enqueue_count|dequeue_count)` and action `keep`.

Comment: If latter I guess(!) you could use pattern in your config like this: `org.apache.activemq<type=Broker, brokerName=(\S*), destinationType=Topic, destinationName=(\S*)><>(enqueue_count|dequeue_count)`

Comment: Yes I am in fact interested in both, but for now I am happy if it works for one. The suggestion you posted is already tried and did not work unfortunately.

Comment: it would be better if you post what you've tried and how exactly it didn't work/failed you expectations.

Answer (score -2):

Check out the examples from the prometheus jmx_exporter. They show you how to configure fields and for what prometheus type-- COUNTER, GAUGE, etc.

For enqueue count & dequeue count you'll want COUNTER

ref: https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/tree/main/example_configs

Comment: The snippet I use above and in my code is from same place. So I used that to try already and could not get it working. Why is enqueue/dequeue showing up now already while I have no counter?